# Why Django Showing this kind of error and how to fix it?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path from.import views 

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('about', views.about, name='about'),
    path('ourwork', views.ourwork, name='ourwork'),
    path('portfolio', views.portfolio, name='portfolio'),
    path('blog', views.blog, name='blog'),
    path('careers', views.careers, name='careers'),
    path('contact', views.contact, name='contact'),

]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
# Create your views here.


def index(request):
    return render(request,'artsoft/index.html')

def about(request):
    return render(request,'artsoft/about.html')

def ourwork(request):
    return render(request,'artsoft/ourwork.html')

def portfolio(request):
    return render(request,'artsoft/portfolio.html')

def blog(request):
    return render(request,'artsoft/blog.html')

def careers(request):
    return render(request,'artsoft/careers.html')

def contact(request):
    return render(request,'artsoft/contact.html') `
```

**screen shot**

[The Error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqXzq.png)

but when i clicking on blog this is work

[Blog page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKTrd.png)

[views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgWIM.png)

[urls.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rckvp.png)

[directories of files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ut2vw.png)

Answer (score 2):

That because you `/about/` has a slash at the end but `/blog` didn't. You could go with this:

```py
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('ourwork/', views.ourwork, name='ourwork'),
    path('portfolio/', views.portfolio, name='portfolio'),
    path('blog/', views.blog, name='blog'),
    path('careers/', views.careers, name='careers'),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
```

and by default, Django has `APPEND_SLASH=True`, with this setting Django will add a slash at the end of your url so `domain.com/blog` and other paths which have no slash at the end also work as normal

Comment: Thank you to replying me, but if i'm using slash at the end then i getting one more problem, when i click on "ourwork" after clicking about then the link like 

"http://127.0.0.1:8000/about/ourwork" and 

**
Page not found (404)
**
give me this error

Comment: It’s because your template code I think. Your anchor should be like this ‘<a href=“/ourwork”></a>’. Or maybe use url tag like this : <a href=“{% url ‘app_name.ourwork’ %}”>’

Comment: Thank you so-much sir for give me the solution it's really worked successfully.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see where it worked (blog), you didn't add the last one `/`

One solution is

```py
from django.urls import path from.import views 

urlpatterns = [
    path('/', views.index, name='index'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('ourwork/', views.ourwork, name='ourwork'),
    path('portfolio/', views.portfolio, name='portfolio'),
    path('blog/', views.blog, name='blog'),
    path('careers/', views.careers, name='careers'),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),

]
```

Or in the navigator put

127.0.0.1:8000/blog

127.0.0.1:8000/contact

127.0.0.1:8000/about 
without the last `/`

Comment: Thank you to replying me, but if i'm using slash at the end then i getting one more problem, when i click on "ourwork" after clicking about then the link like 

"http://127.0.0.1:8000/about/ourwork" and 

**
Page not found (404)
**
give me this error

Comment: yes but how to do like **Or in the navigator put
127.0.0.1:8000/blog
127.0.0.1:8000/contact
127.0.0.1:8000/about
without the last /**

Comment: What I said is to put the url as you have been doing but without the last `/`. Because i saw that in the example that worked you didn't put `/` at the end of url